# I am trying to play video using jquery but anchor tag not working while im trying to display video names?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

```html
package controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.sun.corba.se.spi.orbutil.fsm.Action;

import bean.Video;
import dao.Dao;
import daoimpl.daoImpl;

public class DisplayVideo extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  Dao dao=new daoImpl();
  String action=request.getParameter("action");
  if(action.equals("display")){
  ArrayList<Video>al=dao.getAllVideo();
  //PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
  Gson gson=new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(al);
   System.out.println(json);
   response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  response.getWriter().write(json);
  }
 }
}
```

This is my servlet where im getting data in json format.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert("on document ready");
 $('#video').click(function(event) {     
     alert("on click");
        $.post("Controller?action=display",
          function (data) {
          alert("key"+data);
          var json = data;
          alert("value"+json);
        $.each(json, function(key,value) {
   alert("key1"+value);
   var v ="<a href=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/videos/"+value.videoUrl+"target='blank'>"+value.videoUrl+"</a>";

                  $(v).appendTo($content);
        });
       
  });
}); 

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'>
<button id="video">Play</button>
</div>
</body></html>
```

This my sucess.jsp file from here control goes to servlet and get data in json format from database i have only save video name c.mp4,java.mp4 and cpp.mp4 in database also i have create a folder named videos in my webcontent folder in my project and save videos in that folder also.Response getting properly but after printing alert inside each their is nothing print on screen.my requirment is print that all names of video and onclick of link play video in iframe or in popup window.please help me i didnt know the tags which are used.Thanks in Advance.